# Calling specific class method after a dynamic cast - weird behavior

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

This is a different question than the other one I've posted, I have this piece of code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {

    };


    virtual void Method()
    {
        cout << "Base Method";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Method()
    {
        cout << "Override Method";
    }
};


class Derived2 : public Derived
{
public:

    Derived2()
    {

        cout << "Derived2 constructor";
    }
    void Method()
    {
        cout << "Override2 Method";
    }
};

int main()
{

    Base *myPointer = new Derived();

    dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(myPointer)->Derived2::Method();

    Sleep(700);

    delete myPointer;

    return 0;
}
```

If I write

```
dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(myPointer)->Method();
```

there's a failure (dynamic_cast returns NULL and NULL->Method() provokes an exception) and this is what I was expecting, but if I write

```
dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(myPointer)->Derived2::Method();
```

the function succeeds without even calling the Derived2 constructor. Method isn't even a static function, what is going on here?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but using `delete` on a pointer to `Base` which actually points to an object with dynamic type `Derived` is UB since `Base` doesn't have a virtual destructor. This can be avoided by not using `new`/`delete` altogether: use a `Derived` variable, and then have a pointer (or reference) to `Base` point to (refer to) it. It doesn't hurt to make the destructor virtual though.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Add a member to `Derived2` and attempt to access it inside `Derived2::Method`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You triggered undefined behavior by calling a member function on a NULL pointer. If you use `dynamic_cast`, you must either check the returned pointer for NULL before dereferencing it or 100% ensure you *never* cast to a type that is not the type of the object being cast or one of its parents.

Comment: Check it. `Derived2* myPointer = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(myPointer); if (myPointer == NULL) ...`

Comment: @David, nothing "turns into" a null pointer, `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer if the cast fails, which happens because `myPointer` doesn't point to an object of type `Derived2`

Answer (score 2):

When you do `Derived2::Method();` you are telling the compiler exactly what function to call. This means that it will call it *directly*. (also, your member function does nothing and does not rely on any member variables, so it is easy to call it directly and doesn't crash because it doesn't access anything). In your first example though, because you did not explicitly tell it which function to call, it has to lookup the function, but since you are calling it on a null pointer, the program crashes.

However, in either case you are invoking undefined behavior, and what I explained above is just an implementation detail, which may differ with other implementations.

Answer (score -1):

Undefined behaviour. Your code violates strict aliasing, even if your implementation was bugged and `dynamic_cast` *didn't* return NULL when it should (or if you changed it to `static` or `reinterpret` casts) and a bunch of other mean stuff by attempting to perform this functionality. What you observe as output is irrelevant.

Comment: This has nothing to do with strict aliasing, it's undefined behaviour because it dereferences a null pointer.

Comment: Because there is no `Derived2` object at that location, yet he aliases it with one. So even if he used `static_cast`, it would still be UB.